# How to resize an image made up of 2x2 pixel blocks down to corresponding single pixels?

Tags: resize

I have an image made up of "pixel blocks" of size 2x2 (so that each block is made up of four pixels of the same color). How can I scale the image by a factor of 2 in each direction so as to reduce each 2x2 block to a single pixel (1x1), without any type of smoothing? My preferred graphics tool is GIMP, but I obviously accept answers based on any tool!
/Andreas

Comment: Surely just resizing it normally would do this? As long as you exactly halve each dimension?

Comment: Yes, I just realized that a simple rescaling did the trick, as long as the number of pixels in each direction is an even number to begin with. If it isn't, there is a lot of unwelcome "bleeding" of color shades. That's where I went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if your original image dimensions are odd, you can avoid blurring when scaling down by selecting "None" as the interpolation method in the *Scale Image* dialog:

1. Select *Scale Image...* from the *Image* menu.
2. Select "percent" as the unit in the *Image Size* section.
3. Enter "50" as the width and press enter.  GIMP will set both the width and the height to 50%, and round them up to the nearest pixel.
4. Select the interpolation method "None" in the *Quality* section.

   [image: Screenshot]
5. Click the *Scale* button.

Comment: Ah, so that was embarrassingly easy too. Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

uhmm, if you are using PS:

1. press ctrl-t
2. hold shift
3. re-shape for perfect resize